# Wait for all threadpools

Tags: vb.net, threadpool

I need to wait for all threadpools to be finished before continuing on.   Can someone help me out.  I think I need an array of manualresetevents but can't quite get it.  Thanks.

```
For Each _pdsDir In _config.PDSDirectories
            If Directory.Exists(_pdsDir.ScanDir) Then
                Dim _copyInfo As New CopyInfo
                _copyInfo.ext = ".txt"
                _copyInfo.ScanDir = _pdsDir
                _copyInfo.HoldDir = _config.PDSHoldDirectory
                If _config.Threading Then
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf CopyToHold), _copyInfo)  
                Else
                    CopyToHold(_copyInfo)
                End If
            Else
                LogMessages("PDS Directory does not exist: " + _pdsDir.ScanDir, Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, "816", "E", False, True)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Easiest thing is to have a variable you increment when sending something to the queue and decrement at the end of the `CopyToHold` process. Make sure you increment/decrement inside a synclock.

Comment: I'm reading a lot on countdownevent or how would I code it in.  All the examples I find are not passing any information to the waitcallback.